# Why does my program return "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I remove a conditional in "else if"?

Tags: c, cs50

I've written a program that allows me take a command argument of 26 alpha chars to be used as a key at a latter stage of my program to encipher text.

To do this, I had to (a) verify user input alpha chars (b) chars are 26 and (c) none of them repeat.

I decided to put this all in one function(as you'll see below).
This has been successful.

How ever, when I was trying to check whether the key is indeed 26 chars (in my main function) using an `else if` condition `else if (argc != 2 || (is_valid_key(argv[1]) != 1 || is_valid_key(argv[2]) == 2))` I thought that `(is_valid_key(argv[1]) != 1` may be useless here sinced I used it in `if`.

When I did this(regardless of my command argument) my program returned Segmentation fault (core dumped) and I am trying to understand why.

The line causing the problem is `else if` in my main function.

for context:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_valid_key(string verify);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check whether the user passed a valid command line argument
    if (argc != 2 || is_valid_key(argv[1]) == 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n"); //re-prompt user if they didn't enter a digit
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argc != 2 || is_valid_key(argv[2]) == 2))
    {
        printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string plain_text = get_string("plaintext: ");

    printf("%s\n", plain_text);
}

int is_valid_key(string verify)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < verify[i]; i++)
    {
        char ch = verify[i];

        if (!isalpha(ch))
        {
            return 1; //return for alpha
        }
     }

     if (i != 26)
     {
        return 2; //return for 26 chars
     }

     for (int a = 0; verify[a] != '\0'; a++)
     {
        for (int b = 0; b < a; b++)
        {
            // if 2 characters match, the key is not valid
            if (verify[a] == verify[b])
                return 3; // return for no repeat
        }
    }

    return 4; //return all correct
}
```

Comment: Which is the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault? Find out by running program in a debugger. Then continue using the debugger to help you find the problem. Learning to debug effectively for yourself is much better than relying on others to debug on your behalf.

Comment: `i < verify[i]` what is that meant to check? Considering that `verify` is a string and `verify[i]` is a single ascii character (not an integer). Maybe you meant that to be just `verify[i]` (that is `verify[i] != 0`)

Comment: @kaylum - it is  the "else if"  line
I am trying to learn to debug however my debugger constantly crashes when I try using it

Comment: if you remove an `else if` branch containing a `return` statement and the program crashes afterwards… then the `return` must play a role here

Comment: What exactly is your command line? You should check `argc` before trying to access any `argv` values.

Comment: @kaylum - The exact command line argument is use is "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
in my main I do deck for argc first. Or do you mean I should do it a different manner?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `argc` check. But it is not correct. Since you access `argv[2]` you need the check to be `argc != 3`. Otherwise you should not be accessing `argv[2]` here `is_valid_key(argv[2]) == 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not checking the correct argument in `main()`.

It's testing `is_valid_key(argv[2])` but in your test case of only a single command-line parameter:

```
# ./main qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

There is only:

- `argv[0]` which points to the string "./main"  (or whatever your executable is called)
- `argv[1]` which points to the string "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

The referenced `argv[2]` does not exist, and references "off the end" of `argv`, hence the segfault.

Changing this line to:

```
else if (argc >= 2 || is_valid_key(argv[1]) == 2)   // <<-- HERE
{
    printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault means that you are trying to access a memory location which you shouldn't have. The indexing of arguments starts from 0. And there should be only 2 command-line arguments in this program. So, you are trying to access the index 2 which is out of bounds currently. So, your program exits saying 'Segmentation Fault'.